# How do I dereference links when extracting from a tar file?

Tags: files, symlink, tar

If I have a tar file, `bob.tar`, which contains `real_file` and `link_to_real_file`, in which the latter is a symlink, is there a way to extract the contents of `bob.tar` so that `link_to_real_file` will not be a symlink, but be a copy of `real_file`.

I know this is indeed possible on the creation side, if I use the `-h` flag.

The command `tar -cvhf bob.tar real_file link_to_real_file` will dereference `link_to_real_file`, but I want to do this on the extraction side regardless of how the tar file was created.

Comment: See also [a similar question about hard links](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265024/unpacking-tarball-with-hard-links-on-a-file-system-that-doesnt-support-hard-lin).

Answer (score 3):

Mount the archive as a directory, for example with [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), then use your favorite file copying tool.

```
mountavfs
cp -RLp ~/.avfs$PWD/bob.tar\# target-directory/
```

Comment: A serious caveat to this is if you are attempting to solve this problem when running inside a containerized build system, where mountavfs is not an option as the fuse kernel module is not loaded. We need an answer that covers this.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

1. Extract the archive
2. Recreate the archive using `-h`
3. Extract again