# Ignore Symlinks when Extracting Tarball

Tags: linux, symlink, tar, gnu

I am attempting to extract a tarball (*.tgz, to be exact) and receiving terminal errors on extracted symlinks.  Unfortunately, I cannot simply recreate the archive as this is a legacy archive for a system that no longer exists which was created before I was even out of high school (have to love working for a big company).

I have consulted the almighty Google; however all I can seem to find is information for excluding / following symlinks at *creation* time.  The exact error I am receiving is something of a misnomer (error: read-only filesystem) and comes from the fact that a very large portion of the data payload is contained within numerous squash / cram / loop filesystems.  The symlinks are referencing data within them which, obviously, cannot be mounted due to errors while extracting said tarball.  Chicken; meet egg.

So, in short:

**How can I extract a *.tgz archive to completion while either ignoring symlinks or ignoring resultant symlink errors?**

For reference:

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.7.9-205.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Feb 24 20:10:02 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please post a transcript of untarring, and the output of `tar -xvf`. Are these symlinks to directories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-h (or --dereference) to dereference will only work upon creation.

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC138

According to a similar answer here: [How do I dereference links when extracting from a tar file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22998/how-do-i-dereference-links-when-extracting-from-a-tar-file)  you can mount the archive then copy from it, though I have not tested this myself.

Comment: Handy little tidbit to know, thanks!  For those who may come looking later: AVFS does work, however it is not immediately available for Fedora 18 x64.  It can, however be download without issue and locally installed via yum (use yum; it will grab the FUSE dependency for you).  Once I was 'in' the *.tgz archive, the copy went off without a hitch.

Comment: Just putting in a thought from the linked question, the avfs mounting method does not cover use cases where this needs to be done inside of a containerized build system. Fuse is not available and would require a privileged container. So a method to do this without fuse is needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you like can easily be done. Call:

```
star -x f=archive.tgz -find ! -type l
```

Recent `star` sources are in the `schilytools` package. `star` is the oldest free tar implementation.