# Extracting a symlink-containing tarball on git bash

Tags: bash, windows, tar, git

I wanted to extract a compiler's tarball on git bash on Windows 10:

```
$ tar  xzf  polyml-5.8.2.tar.gz
tar: polyml-5.8.2/compile: Cannot create symlink to ‘/usr/share/automake-1.16/compile’: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Searching on the error messages I have found some advice:

[Ignore Symlinks when Extracting Tarball](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/ignore-symlinks-when-extracting-tarball)

But it says

> -h (or --dereference) to dereference will only work upon creation

[How do I dereference links when extracting from a tar file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22998/how-do-i-dereference-links-when-extracting-from-a-tar-file)

suggest to use mountavs, but git bash on Windows is a very minimal system, I hope to make it work without installing anything.

So, is there a way to make tar not trying to extract a symbolic link to /usr/share?