# unpacking tarball with hard links on a file system that doesn't support hard links

Tags: tar, hard-link, afs

I got a tarball (let's say `t.tar.gz`) that contains the following files

```
./a/a.txt
./b/b.txt
```

where `./b/b.txt` is a hard link to `./a/a.txt`.

I want to unpack the tarball on a network file system (AFS) that only supports hard links in the same directory (see [here](http://www.angelfire.com/hi/plutonic/afs-faq.html#sub2.01)).
Therefore, just unpacking it via `tar -xzf t.tar.gz` raises an error that the hard link `./b/b.txt` cannot be created.

So far, my solution to the problem was to unpack `./t.tar.gz` on a file system that supports ordinary hard links. Then pack it again with the option `--hard-dereference` as [the GNU tar manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/hard-links.html) proposes. And lastly, unpack that new tarball into the AFS.

As this is unsatisfactory for me, I'm asking if there is an easier way to get the content of the archive unpacked directly to it's final destination? Such as an equivalent option to `--hard-dereference` for unpacking instead of archiving?

Comment: it [appears not](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC141), to me

Comment: Given JeffSchaller's comment, may I suggest "[How do I dereference links when extracting from a tar file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22998/how-do-i-dereference-links-when-extracting-from-a-tar-file)"? This `mountavfs` approach appears quite simple.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I don't think that makes the questions duplicates. Many solutions will work for both, to be sure, but there could be solutions for hard links that don't work for symbolic links or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount the archive as a directory, for example with [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), then use your favorite file copying tool.

```
mountavfs
cp -a --no-preserve=links ~/.avfs/path/to/t.tar.gz\# target-directory/
```

or

```
mountavfs
rsync -a ~/.avfs/path/to/t.tar.gz\#/ target-directory/
```

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to mountavfs. This seems to be the best option for me right now.